# A JavaScript closure confusion

Tags: javascript, closures

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hS9x4/)

```
function f1(){
    var n=999;

    nAdd=function(){n+=1;};

    function f2(){
        alert(n);
    }
    return f2;
}

var result = f1();
var result2 = f1();

result();  // 999
nAdd();
result2(); // 1000
result2(); // 1000
result();  // 999
```

I am trying to learn JavaScript closures, but the code above just got me confused.
When the first time `result()` is called , it's 999. That's ok for me.

After `nAdd()` is called, `result2()` shows 1000. And I think this is due to function `result2()` and function `result()` are equals to function `f1()`.

But why does the last `result()` show 999 instead of 1000?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Each time `f1()` is called that creates a new closure with its own local `n` variable.

However, the `nAdd` variable is global, and so gets overwritten every time `f1()` is called - which means calling `nAdd()` will only ever add to the `n` variable in the *last* closure.

UPDATE: If you want to be able to increment the values of `n` in each closure independently you could do something like this:

```
function f1(){
    var n=999;
    return {
        incrementN : function(){n+=1;},
        getN : function f2(){console.log(n);}
    }
}    
var result = f1();
var result2 = f1();
result.getN(); // 999
result.incrementN();
result2.getN();//999
result2.incrementN();
result2.getN();//1000
result.getN();//1000
```

That is, have `f1()` return an object containing two methods that are not declared as globals, and that both operate on the local `n` variable from the closure they belong to.

Answer (score 28):

There're already good answers, but I guess a picture would be helpful to understand.

[image]

Comment: Yeah! Clearer than other answers

Comment: Surely the BEST answer!!

Comment: Very clear explanation! Thank you. Just one more quick question: why is the statement `return f2` will cause `f2` to be invoked? (not `f2()`)

Comment: @Bao `return f2` will not cause f2 to be invoked; the invocation is because either `result` or `result2` being called.

Answer (score 13):

Each time you call `f1()` you:

- Create a new (local) variable called `n` with a value of `999`
- Create a new nameless function assigned to the **global** `nAdd` that modifies that `n` (and overwrites any previous function assigned to `nAdd`)
- Create a new function that you return which alerts the value of that `n`

You call `f1()` twice, so you do all that of that twice. The second time you call it, you overwrite `nAdd` with a new function that modifies the *second* `n`.

This leaves you with:

- `result()` which alerts the **first** `n`
- `result2()` which alerts the **second** `n`
- `nAdd()` which increments the **second** `n`

`result()` on the last line alerts `999` because it alerts the value of the *first* `n` (which has never been incremented).

Comment: The variable *nAdd* is created once: the first time *f1* is called at the point where the assignment statement is evaluated. After that, it's just the value that changes each time *f1* is called. Maybe that's just another way of saying what you said. :-/

Answer (score 4):

`result` and `result2` contain the result of different invocations of `f1` and hence contain different instances of the local variable `n`. Each invocation of a function may have different values for the local variables of that function. That does even apply when no closures are involved.

Comment: +1. Each time an execution context is entered, a new set of variables are created.

Answer (score 1):

The `nAdd=function(){n+=1;};` line creates a global function which is a closure inside `f1()`. A closure has access too all variables from scope of the function which created it. So each time you call `f1()` it creates a new `nAdd()` function which has `n` value bound to value of `var n` of the call of `f1()`.

In your code;

```
var result = f1();
var result2 = f1();
result(); // 999
nAdd();         // Created by "var result2 = f1();" and has the same 'n' value as function in result2
result2();//1000
result2();//1000
result();//999
```

Answer (score 0):

the result and result2 create two different closures with different n. If you make n a global variable by declaring it outside of the f1() function, then you will get the result that you had expected since in that case you will always be accessing the global variable n:

> var n=999;
>   function f1(){
>   nAdd=function(){n+=1;};
>   function f2(){
>   console.log(n);
>   }
>   return f2;
>   }
>   var result = f1();
>   var result2 = f1();
>   result(); // 999
>   nAdd();
>   result2();//1000
>   result2();//1000
>   result();//1000

Answer (score 0):

it like that：

```
var nAdd;
function f1(){
    var n=999;

    nAdd=function(){n+=1;};

    function f2(){
        alert(n);
    }
    return f2;
}

var result = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result.n=999

var result2 = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result2.n=999

var result3 = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result3.n=999

nAdd();

result();  // 999

result2(); // 999

result3(); // 1000

var result = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result.n=999

var result2 = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result2.n=999

nAdd();

var result3 = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result3.n=999


result();  // 999

result2(); // 1000

result3(); // 999

var result = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result.n=999

var result2 = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result2.n=999

nAdd();

var result3 = f1();//var nAdd=function(){n+=1;} n=result3.n=999
nAdd(); 
nAdd();
nAdd();   

result();  // 999

result2(); // 1000

result3(); // 1002
```

Comment: I guess this guy shows 3 fragments, each ends with code "result3();". Then it can be understood.